# UserControl not showing in designer when created

Tags: c#, .net-core, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

Whenever I add a UserControl to my Visual Studio 16.6 C# Windows Form program it will not allow me to open the designer for it. Instead it will give me this error "Expected a proxy type, Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinForms.RemoteClient.Proxies.ComponentProxy." The code works I can view it and run it, I just can't edit the UserControl in the designer.

Here is the call stack...

"at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinForms.RemoteClient.Proxies.Extensions.ToComponentProxy(Object obj)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinForms.RemoteClient.DesignerSession.InitializeRootComponent(CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, ResourceContentData[] resourceDocDataContent)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinForms.RemoteClient.Loader.RemoteCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)"

Comment: Yes .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to delete the .vs folder and restart VS. The .vs folder is in the same folder like the solution.

Comment: What happens when you create a new project? Same error?

Comment: Interesting. When I create a new project it works as it should

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but deleting the .vs folder didn't solve the problem.

If you want to reproduce the error: Create a C# .net core Windows Form project, then add a new User Control into the project. When I do that I get the error descriped above. The problem is descriped [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/760941/error-opening-design-editor-for-custom-control.html) aswell.

This is yet unsupported (VS2019 V16.6.2) and you need to install the [Preview Version](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) of VS2019 if you want to use it.

This solved the problem for me (used VS2019 Preview V16.7.0 Preview 3.0).
Hopefully this will be added to the non-Preview Version of Visual Studio soon.